# Crunchbang hibernate rebooted system?

Tags: debian, desktop, crunchbang, hibernate, reboot

I installed the latest stable 64bit Crunchbang backport. When I tried to hibernate it last night, it rebooted into the locked state - when I logged back in all my windows/apps were as they were again.

Two things:

- How do I get Crunchbang to hibernate? hibernate works in my Windows7 partition. Crunchbang is installed on a separate physical drive than Windows and the bios.
- How did Crunchbang effectively shutdown and restart with the state of all my opened apps intact? If this a feature can someone tell me how to do it explicitly because it would be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crunchbang did exactly what hibernate is meant to do.

Hibernate writes the contents of your RAM to the disk and shuts the machine down. When you power your machine up again it detects that there is a RAM image file stored on disk and loads the contents of the RAM image back into RAM.

You need to enter your password because it is configured that way in Crunchbang, which is a good thing because otherwise the person that would start your machine could access your machine without a password.

So Crunchbang does exactly what Windows 7 does, just the looks of the process are different.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's just more sensitive than windows then :)
Is there a method of hibernating then that reactivates not on feedback from input device like mouse/keyboard but instead on pressing the power button?

Comment: Depending on what you want you could try to suspend your machine. The difference between suspend and hibernate is that suspend keeps the RAM powered up, so that the contents don't get lost.
Suspend is normally configured that it wakes up from keyboard/mouse, but it could be that you need to configure your BIOS to wake up from USB devices.